# How can I create a new derived datatype from a struct type in MPI?

Tags: c++, c, struct, mpi, cluster-computing

I'm creating new derived datatype for MPI to send data from Counter struct  and you knew creating new type in MPI is painful and tricky  because I need some help to if I am on right track and thank you ?

```
typedef struct Counter{
int range1,range2,range3,range4;
double preset1 ,preset2 ,preset3 ,preset4;
}  countType;

MPI_Datatype createRecType()
{
    // Set-up the arguments for the type constructor
    MPI_Datatype new_type;
    int count = 2;

    int blocklens[] = { 4, 4 };
    MPI_Aint indices[4];
    indices[0] = 0;
     MPI_Type_extent( MPI_DOUBLE, &indices[1] );
     indices[1] *= 4;    // There are 2 doubles
    MPI_Datatype old_types[] = { MPI_INT ,MPI_DOUBLE};
        // Call the data type constructor
    MPI_Type_struct(count, blocklens, indices, old_types, &new_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&new_type);

    return new_type;
}
```

Comment: what is `drive datatype`? I know not a little about MPI, but I cannot match that to anything.. do you mean `derived datatype`, i.e a structure with several fields that will behave as 'an item' of a buffer?

Comment: If you meant 'derived', please correct your question and subject. 'Drive' is misleading. I'm not correcting that, because I'm, not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I guessed right, then see https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/#Derived_Data_Types and the section "Examples: Struct Derived Data Type". It presents how to describe a "particle" defined as:

```
typedef struct {
   float x, y, z;
   float velocity;
   int  n, type;
} Particle;
```

so that MPI can handle an array of them. The whole relevant snippet is:

```
/* Setup description of the 4 MPI_FLOAT fields x, y, z, velocity */
offsets[0] = 0;
oldtypes[0] = MPI_FLOAT;
blockcounts[0] = 4;

/* Setup description of the 2 MPI_INT fields n, type */
/* Need to first figure offset by getting size of MPI_FLOAT */
MPI_Type_extent(MPI_FLOAT, &extent);
offsets[1] = 4 * extent;
oldtypes[1] = MPI_INT;
blockcounts[1] = 2;

/* Now define structured type and commit it */
MPI_Type_struct(2, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &particletype);
MPI_Type_commit(&particletype);
```

Your code seems to follow all of that. Unless you have some typos, your code seems OK. But I cannot guarantee it unless I try compiling and running that;)

One thing for sure, your `indices` is too large. [2] will be enough. But having it larger will not do anything bad. The `count` says 2, so MPI will not read those extra elements from that array.

Comment: And remember that you have to make sure that ALL nodes will define the same structure in the same way. If you run one identical program on all of them, than no worries, they will. But if you do some branches on ranks and have ie. #0-master, #1..#n-slaves, then ensure that both slaves and master defines it. It's easy to forget it at master node.

Comment: can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170511/how-to-send-derived-datatype-to-process-master-to-printed-out-mpi

Comment: @melnajjar: I've checked, but It seems you have deleted it already:)

Comment: I post new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180274/my-gather-buffer-is-empty-mpi