# My gather Buffer is Empty?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, cluster-computing

I have problem gathering data from all process to process master "root" I can send the data MPI_Bcast but the on MPI_Gather I have all the problem in my countBuff  I debug my output and this is what I have

```
output 

    brodcast data of 0
    brodcast data of 1
    MPI_Gather data rank 0 1
    from 0 to 1.00 KM:-842150451,from 1.00 to 2.00 KM:-842150451,from 2.00 to 5.00 KM:-842150451,grater than 5.00 KM:-842150451
    MPI_Type_free1
    delete countBuff
    MPI_Finalize
    brodcast data of 2
    MPI_Gather data rank 0 0
    MPI_Gather data rank 0 2
    from 0 to 1.00 KM:-842150451,from 1.00 to 2.00 KM:-842150451,from 2.00 to 5.00 KM:-842150451,grater than 5.00 KM:-842150451
    MPI_Type_free2
    delete countBuff
    MPI_Finalize

    job aborted:
    rank: node: exit code[: error message]
    0:: -1073741819: process 0 exited without calling finalize
    1:: 123
    2:: 123


the code 


void ProcesData(int rank,int numProcs)
{

    static countType count;
    MPI_Datatype recType = createRecType();
    //read file and populate the vectors
    ifstream foodbankFile("foodbanks.dat");
    ifstream residenceFile("residences.dat");

    // populate datavector
    std::vector<Foodbank> foodbankData((std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(foodbankFile)),
        std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>());

    Residence res;
    int numLines = 0;


    while(!residenceFile.eof())
    {
        residenceFile >> res.x >>res.y;


        if ( numLines % numProcs == rank)
        {
            //call the  process
            //populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData);
            analysis_range(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData),count);

        }
        ++numLines;

    }


    cout<<"brodcast data of "<<rank<<endl;
    MPI_Bcast(&count, 1, recType, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Type_free(&recType);
    //std::cout<< "for Rank"<<rank<< ",from 0 to 1.00 KM:"<<count.range1<<",%"<<count.preset1
    //<<",from 1.00 to 2.00 KM:"<<count.range2<<",%"<<count.preset2<<",from 2.00 to 5.00 KM:"
    //<<count.range3<<",%"<<count.preset3<<",grater than 5.00 KM:"<<count.range4<<",%"<<count.preset3<<std::endl;
}


    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {

        if( MPI_Init(&argc, &argv) == MPI_SUCCESS )
        {
            // Get the number of processes and the rank of this process
            int procRank,numProcs;
            MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);
            MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procRank);


            ProcesData(procRank,numProcs);


            // Create a derived type for passing the rec array
            MPI_Datatype recType = createRecType();
            static countType count;
            countType* countBuff  = new countType[numProcs];

            MPI_Gather(&count, 1, recType, &countBuff, 1, recType,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            cout<<"MPI_Gather data rank 0 "<<procRank<<endl;
            //MPI_Allgather(&count, 1, recType, &countBuff, 1, recType,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            std::cout<<"from 0 to 1.00 KM:"<<countBuff[0].range1<<",from 1.00 to 2.00 KM:"
                <<countBuff[0].range2<<",from 2.00 to 5.00 KM:"<<countBuff[0].range3
                <<",grater than 5.00 KM:"<<countBuff[0].range4<<std::endl;


            cout<<"MPI_Type_free"<<procRank<<endl;
            MPI_Type_free(&recType);
            cout<<"delete countBuff"<<endl;

            cout<<"MPI_Finalize"<<endl;
            MPI_Finalize();


        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I did part on number one but I could the  COLLECTIVE INTERFACE to send the data to master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   void processData(int rank,int numProcs)
    {

        static countType count;
        MPI_Datatype recType = createRecType();

        //read file and populate the vectors
        ifstream foodbankFile("foodbanks.dat");
        ifstream residenceFile("residences.dat");

        // populate datavector
        std::vector<Foodbank> foodbankData((std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(foodbankFile)),
            std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>());

        Residence res;
        int numLines = 0;


        while(!residenceFile.eof())
        {
            residenceFile >> res.x >>res.y;


            if ( numLines % numProcs == rank)
            {

                analysis_range(getShortestDistances(res,foodbankData),count);

            }
            ++numLines;

        }

        countType* countBuff  = new countType[numProcs];
        MPI_Gather(&count, 1, recType, countBuff, 1, recType,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(rank == 0)
    {

        static countType countArggResult;
        for (int p = 0; p < numProcs; ++p)
        {
                   // out put result 
}
    }


    //free virables
    delete []  countBuff;
    MPI_Type_free(&recType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I've misread your post. Sorry.

Look at this code:

```
        ProcesData(procRank,numProcs);


        // Create a derived type for passing the rec array
        MPI_Datatype recType = createRecType();
        static countType count;
        countType* countBuff  = new countType[numProcs];

        MPI_Gather(&count, 1, recType, &countBuff, 1, recType,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        cout<<"MPI_Gather data rank 0 "<<procRank<<endl;
```

The problem is that MPI_Gather sends `&count`.  But read the code carefully. What is the value of the `count` that will be sent?

Either you have misunderstood the Bcast and Gather - They are not related. Not at all! - or, you have wrongly assumed that the "count" from ProcessData will magically flow into "count" from main. They won't. Those are different variables. In such case, just `return` the count from ProcessData.

Check the examples at http://mpitutorial.com/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/ they are quite similar to what you are trying to do.

EDIT:

hm.. actually, after reading your code 4th time, I don't understand what and where you want to send. Make your mind: do you want to SEND the 'count' to all workers, or do you want to READ the counts from all workers? If you want a typical case, when some workers read some parts of the input file, then each calculates something, then the results are 'gathered' - see the link above. Otherwise, you will have to elaborate, because my imagination's ended.

Comment: Hi I finally found the solution I will answer my Question soon ;)